# I can't tell all clients to clear their browser cache!

Tags: magento2, cache, static-content, static-content-deploy

recently we have changed few files `js/CSS/phtml` files on our site as we tested them we experienced strange thing in incognito mode the new *`CSS`* and *`js`* is working fine but if we switched to normal mode it loads the old files. The issue was a browser cache as we cleared browser cache everything worked as well. But the problem is that we can't tell our every client to clear their browser cache. Is there any Solution!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method helped me  I have added `urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()` in my **requirejs-config.js** file now the cache issue is solved for now.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            bssAjaxCart: 'Vendor_Module/js/ajax'
        }
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()// Disable require js cache
};
```

REFERENCES:

[magestore-blog](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/disable-requirejs-cache-magento-2/)

[requirejs-doc](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs)

[stackissue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts)

Answer (score 2):

Enable cache busting on static file URLs. This ensures users get the latest version of the assets anytime they update:

```
php -f bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To overcome these issues Magento features **Static Content Signing** which allows you to invalidate **Browser Cache**. You can enable static content signing by navigating to **`Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings`**, Set `Sign Static Files` to Yes. Once done each time when you run the deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Magento changes the version number so automatically your static files in browser cache are invalidated due to version number change.

http://website.com/pub/static/version1475604434/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/image.png

You can also enable/disable static content signing through this command

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign <1 or 0>
```

Comment: `Sign Static Files` is already set to `yes`

Comment: Are you using PWA or any third party cache?

Comment: are you talking about cache buster??

Comment: Since you are saying have enabled static content signing and still the browser cache doesn't get cleared upon deploying files after css/js change, if you have installed any third party cache servers like varnish etc. or making use of technologies like PWA it might cause troubles for changes to be reflected on end user device

Comment: is there any solution for pwa or varnish??

Comment: Have you installed any of those.

Comment: yes varnish is installed

Comment: If varnish is installed these are the steps you will be doing to clear cache after changes to CSS or static files 1. Deploy static files 2. Clean Magento css/js cache to clear merged/bundled files 3. Clean Magento cache 4. Clean varnish cache. This might solve your issue.

Comment: Hi we installed a PWA and this is happening to us now. Do you know how to fix with PWA?